# Estimate of a sample size of a search algorithm

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I am trying to estimate the order of the sample size of a probabilistic search algorithm. The problem is the following: 
I have a counting problem where an oracle can identify the right solution, i.e. returns $1$ if the sample is a solution to the problem and $0$ otherwise. We assume there are $N$ items (search space) to check and $M$ are correct (the solution to our search problem).
During the procedure the algorithm can draw only $k$ samples from the search space which will lead to a series of oracle outputs $X_1, \ldots, X_k$ (hence a sequence of $1$s and $0$s). The algorithm then returns the estimate $S = N \cdot \sum_j X_j /k $
I now want to find the standard deviation of this algorithm in order to find the the number of samples for which the probability of estimatimating $M$ within an error of $\sqrt{M}$ is at least $3/4$.

Can anyone help me how to calculate it? I started with $(\Delta S)^2 = \sum_i \left( \left<S \right> - S_i \right)$ where $i$ is the number of all possible samples (i.e. $N$ over $k$ i suppose). But when plugging in $S$ i didn't know how to proceed. I know the right solution of the std has to be $\Delta S = \sqrt{M(N-M)/k}$ but i can't see neither how to get there nor how to proceed.

Comment: To my understanding you are not interested in the change of the standard deviation but the moment standard deviation as the sample size grows. This could be achieved by computing the current standard deviation using the samples at each step of the algorithm, assuming that the number of samples grow with each iteration. There are faster ways to find a treshold though. For example, using accelerated stochastic approximation. Did I understand your question correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variance, which is the square of the standard deviation, is $\sigma^2=\overline{S^2}-(\overline{S})^2$.
The expected value of $S$ is $\overline S=\sum_i\frac NkE(X_i)=\sum_i\frac Nk\frac MN$.
The expected value of $S^2$ is $$\overline{S^2}=\frac{N^2}{k^2}\left(kE(X_i^2)+k(k-1)E_{i\neq j}(X_iX_j)\right)$$

That is because there are $k^2$ terms in $S^2$, $k$ of these terms involve the square of the same $X_i$, and the other $k(k-1)$ involve a pair of different $X_i$.

What is the average value of $X_i^2$?  What is the average value of $X_iX_j$ when we know they are different samples?  Hint: Count the possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for the description! So i would say the following, but I am far from certain:
Since we deal with boolean values ($0$ or $1$) the expectation value of $X_i$ should be equal to the expectation value of $X_i^2$ so $\frac{M}{N}$, while the expectation value of $X_i X_j$, since they are independent samples we have a probability for each of the k values to be $1$ of  $M/N$. I was thinking about the sum of the binomial distribution, but I think I am not heading in the right direction there?

Comment: Since $X_i\neq X_j$, the probability is $M(M-1)/N(N-1)$

Comment: Hmm, okay, that makes sense of course if I draw those $X_i X_j$. 
Sorry I was thinking that the $k$ matters as well. Hmm would it be different if the $k$ would be bigger than the $M$? (Just for me to comprehend it a bit better).
Do you have any hint how to proceed with the estimate of the guessing the right $M$ then?